# Spark Java - User Defined function is not getting called using collect()using spark-submit in yarn cluster

Tags: spark-java

I have registered an user defined function, if the column value is null return some value

```
     spark.udf().register("replaceFunctions",replaceFunctions,DataTypes.StringType);


private static UDF1< String, String> replaceFunctions = new UDF1< String, String>() {
        public String call(String input) throws Exception {
            if(input == null)
                return "Test";
            
            
        }
    }
    ;

And my code to call udf is
jdbcDf2.select(col("status"),callUDF("replaceFunctions",col("status"))).collect();
```

User defined function is not getting called in hadoop edge node, but working in local

Comment: is it throw exception?

Comment: No, its not throwing any exception, but function is not getting called.